# first value in group by

Tags: sql, hiveql

I want to set a column in the `group by` table based on the first (actually, only) value in the group.

Specifically, given a table

```
id   good
1    t
1    t
2    f
3    t
```

I want to produce the table

```
id    multiplicity  goodN
1     2             0
2     1             0
3     1             1
```

where `goodN` is 1 if and only if `multiplicity` is 1 and `good` is `t`:

```
select id, count(*) as multiplicity,
       if (count(*) > 1, 0, if(good = 't', 1, 0)) as goodN
from ...
```

The question is: how do I extract the first (in my case, only) value of `good` from the group?

PS. is there a cheaper way to test that the group has size 1 than `count(*)=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the count is 1, then both the MAX(good) and MIN(good) will be the "first" row in the group.

```
select id, count(*) as multiplicity,
       if (count(*) > 1, 0, if(max(good) = 't', 1, 0)) as goodN
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Select good from...
Where id=(select min(id) from...
Where good >0)

And

Group by id having count(id)=1

You can test count(goods) instead of count(*) and  at the end add group by id. To take only record with moltiplicity 1 add having count(goods)=1

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If it were MySQL then simply:

```
SELECT id,
       good,
       count(*) AS multiplicity,
       if((count(*) > 1 AND good = 't'), @flag := 1, @flag := 0) AS goodN
  FROM goods
GROUP BY good, id;
```

PS: Let me know if you want me to delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with hiveql, but this does what you want in mySql. I think should work the same in hiveql.

```
select t.id, count(*) as multiplicity, 
      (select case count(*) when 1 then 1 else 0 end
         from table1
        where id = t.id
          and good = 't') as goodN
  from table1 t
 group by t.id
```

**[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8ee2/18)**